# Redirect to the same path minus the filename using php

Tags: php, apache

So I want to redirect a page in a directory, for example `auth/login.php`, to another page, at `auth/`. The page is actually called `auth/index.php` but I don't want this to show up to the client. How can I do this using this PHP code:

```
header("Location: /auth/");
```

However, I want the filename to be relative, e.g. `../` instead of hard-coded as `auth`. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To direct the users to your current directory, you should extract the script's directory from `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, and then compare it to the actual HTTP request (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`). If they're not the same - redirect to the current directory. If they're the same - you should start your actual script:

```
<?php

$currentScript = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$pathInfo = pathinfo($currentScript);
$currentDir = $pathInfo['dirname'].'/';

if ($currentDir != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
{
  header('Location: '.$currentDir);
  return ;
}

// Here be real site data
```

Comment: Thanks, I one-lined the first three lines for convenience: `$currentdir=pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])['dirname'].'/';`